# Displaying foreign key related tables in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I am trying to create properties list and link it to objects.

**Table : Properties**

```
class Properties(models.Model):
    Property = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4......
    PropetyDesc = models.CharField(max_length= .......
```

**Table : Wood**

```
class Wood(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length= .....
    Property = models.ForeignKey(Properties, on_delete=models......
```

At the outset I am trying to use Django Admin's capabilities to see how the DB design stack up.

In a nutshell my admin page would look like a GUI for creating a purchase order where the header section will have the order details and in the item line we will have materials:

[image]

In the instant case, I am trying to put the object (Wood) on the header and in the "TabularInline" being created will have option to choose the properties.

```
class PropertiesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Properties

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        extra = 1
        return extra

class WoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Name', 'Property')
    fields = ['Name', 'Property'] 
    inlines = [PropertiesInline] 

admin.site.register(Wood, WoodAdmin)
```

However, I end up getting the following error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'mapp.admin.PropertiesInline'>: (admin.E202) 'mapp.Properties' has no ForeignKey to 'mapp.Wood'.
```

On the other hand, if I were to reverse the scenario like this:

```
class WoodInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Wood

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        extra = 1
        return extra

class PropertiesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Property', 'PropetryDesc')
    fields = ['Property', 'PropertyDesc'] 
    inlines = [WoodInline] 

admin.site.register(Properties, PropertiesAdmin)
```

The page loads, but I end up getting the "Property" in the header with option to select various records of "Wood".

Is there a way I can achieve what I am trying to.

Comment: That should have been a hint that your model definitions are wrong. The ForeignKey should be on the 'many' side of the relationship; here, it should be on Property, pointing to Wood.

Comment: Precisely so. But my understanding is that an entity can have many properties (attributes, if you may) but **may not be** the other way around. So in my case, I am averse to defining a FK field in "Properties" pointing to table "Wood". So... is there a way to solve my dilemma?

Comment: I don't understand your objection. The way to allow a Wood to have many Properties is to have the FK on Property pointing to Wood. The way you have it now *would* allow a Property to have many Woods, which is exactly what you say you don't want.

Comment: Unless you read the question you won't understand. Check out the simile as well.

Comment: I did read the question. For the third time, your fk is the wing way round, and swapping it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: It is not. Can you just see the image of the PO. How would you take care of a situation as depicted in the image. Suppose you have a number of materials and want to create a PO by using some of those materials (selecting materials by drop down in the tabular inline just like as shown in the PO). How would you go about creating the most basic table scenario (PO and Material) and depict the situation in Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the dilemma by creating an intermediate table with FK relationship to both the tables. Created a tabular inline with Properties and registered Wood with Properties assigned as inline object. That way I am now able to attach a number of properties to the object (Wood).

[image]